# How to connect php variable into javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, php

As the title says I'm having difficulties connecting php variable into javascript for loop. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    for (i = 3; i <= <?php echo (int)$description_count?>; i++)
    { 
        $("#row"+i).css('display','inline-block');
    }
});
```

It doesn't loop at all, when I try looping with normal number instead of echoing variable everything works fine, what's the problem?

Comment: What's the value of $description_count? Is it >= 3?

Comment: @smottt Yes,it's always higher than 3.

Comment: What exactly does the PHP write to the code? (What's the final output?)

Comment: Check if $description_count is not a string/alphanumeric try `echo $description_count` and see what it prints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there is some syntax error. Check it in view source whether the value comes. Try -

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   for (i = 3; i <= <?php echo $description_count; ?>; i++)
   { 
       $("#row"+i).css('display','inline-block');
   }
});
```

Comment: Tried this way, didn't helped.

Comment: Check it in `view source`

Comment: have you tried this: echo json_encode($description_count);

Comment: @dariusz.g I just got a 'null' out of that,so I'm guessing the mistake is because I'm sending null variable.

Comment: before you fire your js code, just try to var_dump your variable and then look what you are getting exactly in your var

Comment: I'll accept this answer, though dariusz.g got me to the answer, whoever going to need this in future should look at comments. The thing was that instead of writing $lesson_count I wrote $description_count which was the variable of input that I posted, I put that input into $lesson_count variable so that was my foolish mistake, though thanks a lot for helping guys :)